# JS Class method - swapping values between instances

Tags: javascript, class, methods, swap

Learning about classes I noticed an interesting phenomenon, can you please explain how it happens. In class *Infected* I declared a function *infect(somebody)*. In my example of **mary.infect(john)** - while I understand that Mary gets infected (mary is the object I'm calling the function on, mary is the object I'm currently working on, changing mary's property value), **I don't understand how John gets infected from Mary too (john serves as merely an argument in current function call).**

In other words: *mary.infect(john)* - **I'm calling this function 'from' mary object (mary is 'this' object)**, so what kind of magic happens here that **I'm able to change the value of John's diseases as well?**

My thinking was: if I use john as merely a parameter (argument) in a function call to mary, all I can do is extract certain values from john (like his diseases), but I didn't expect I can at the same moment access john and change john's values. It just seemed a bit counter-intuitive to me.

It's cool we can **swap values between two objects** like that. But I don't get how it works.

```
class Infected {
    constructor(name, diseases) {
        this.name = name;
        this.diseases = diseases;
    }
    infect(somebody) {
        const thisDiseases = this.diseases;
        this.diseases = this.diseases.concat(somebody.diseases);
        somebody.diseases = somebody.diseases.concat(thisDiseases);
    }
}

const mary = new Infected('Mary', ['herpes', 'hepatitis']);
const john = new Infected('John', ['flu', 'syphilis']);
mary.infect(john);
mary.diseases ->  ['herpes', 'hepatitis', 'flu', 'syphilis']
john.diseases -> ['flu', 'syphilis', 'herpes', 'hepatitis']
```

Comment: When you pass `john` as an argument, you are actually passing a reference to an object, not a copy. Both `john` and `somebody` point to the same object in memory, so changing `somebody` in `infect` reflects in `john` reference too.